# Hover parent-element shall edit child-elements look - not working

Tags: html, css

I have several figure-elements where I want to add some simple hover-effect to the caption when hovering the parent-container. But that doesn work out, neither with **>** nor in the way shown below, what do I do wrong there?

```
.kategorie_container .product_caption{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1vh 2vw;
    bottom: 0;
    background:white;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.kategorie_container figure:hover .kategorie_container .product_caption {
    background:blue;
}
```

And this is the markup-structure of it:

```
<figure class="col col-3 ">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/media/raster/active-pro80-dose_1.jpg" />
        <div class="product_caption">
        <h6 class="produktname">Productname</h6>
        <h6 class="produktpreis">Productprice</h6>
        </div>
    </a>
</figure>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no element with class `kategorie_container` inside your `figure` element, so naturally your selector containing `figure:hover .kategorie_container` does not match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with the class "kategorie-container" inside your figure. I think you meant to write

```
.kategorie_container figure:hover .product_caption {
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: This is correct.  Here is a JSFiddle that shows it working: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fefh8v4o/1/)